# Ajax response time too long

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">

                            <tbody>
                                <tr>                        
        <td><select  name="ser" id="ser" class="bs-select form-control" onchange="getPrice(this.value);" data-live-search="true" required="">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
        <?php
        $queryprd=$db->execute("select * from product_add where productcode LIKE '%$q%' and delet='0'");
        while($result=$queryprd->fetch_assoc())
        {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $result['productcode']."|".$result['productname'];?>"><?php echo $result['productcode']."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$result['productname'];?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </select></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="sale" id="saleprice"  class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Price"  required=""/></td>
        <td><select class="form-control msre" name="measure[]" id="measure">
            </select></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
    </table>
<script>
        function getPrice(val)
{
   $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: 'get_sales_price.php',
     data: {
       get_option:val
     },
     success: function (response) {
       document.getElementById("saleprice").value=response; 
       getquty(val);
       getmsur(val);
     }
   });
}

function getmsur(val)
{
   $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: 'get_measure.php',
     data: {
       get_option:val
     },
     success: function (response) {
        document.getElementById("measure").innerHTML=response;
        }
   });
}


</script>
```

**get_sales_price.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
require "../model/configuration.php";
$option = $_POST['get_option'];
list($code,$pname) = explode("|", $option);
$name=$pname;
$cod=$code;
$_SESSION['prdcode']=$cod;
$querydep=$db->execute("select * from productsale_price where product_code='$cod'");
$pprce=$querydep->fetch_assoc();
$queryty=$db->execute("select * from product_add where productcode='$cod' and delet='0'");
$resultro=$queryty->fetch_assoc();
$_SESSION['prdtype']=$resultro['product_type'];
$_SESSION['mrp']=$pprce['mrp'];
echo $pprce['sale_price'];
?>
```

**get_measure.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
require "../model/configuration.php";
$option = $_POST['get_option'];
list($code,$pname) = explode("|", $option);
$name=$pname;
$cod=$code;
       $prdqty=$db->execute("select * from master_purchase where product_code='".$cod."' and delet='0' order by master_purchase_id DESC");//and vendor_id='".$_SESSION['vnid']."'
       $tqty=$prdqty->fetch_assoc();
?>

<option value="">--Select--</option><option value="Box" <?php if($tqty['measure']=='Box'){ echo "selected";}?>>Box</option><option value="Ml"<?php if($tqty['measure']=='M'){ echo "selected";}?>>Ml</option>
```

This codes working perfectly but my problem is.... when i select an option from a select box its **id="ser"** i call a function in **onchange="getPrice(this.value);"** its work perfectly ajax result shown in specified fields some times 1 or 3 minutes some times more than 5 minutes how to reduce time wastage 
please help...

Comment: index your table properly, select only the filed that you need in your select query,hope for the best :)))

Comment: $querydep=$db->execute("select sale_price,mrp from productsale_price where product_code='$cod'");
$pprce=$querydep->fetch_assoc();.......like this

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using two SQLs to fetch data, Use one SQL using `LEFT join` it will save some time.

```
<?php
    $querydep=$db->execute("select pp.mrp, pp.sale_price, pa.product_type
    from productsale_price As pp LEFT JOIN product_add As pa 
       ON pa.product_code = pp.product_code AND pa.delet='0' 
        where pp.product_code='$cod'");
    $pprce=$querydep->fetch_assoc();
    $_SESSION['prdtype']=$pprce['product_type'];
    $_SESSION['mrp']=$pprce['mrp'];
    echo $pprce['sale_price'];
?>
```

Comment: those are SQL Aliases

Answer (score 0):

Did you create indexes for the tables productsale_price, product_add and master_purchase ?

If not, you need to index: 
 - productsale_price on product_code
 - product_add on productcode and
 - master_purchase product_code

This should do the trick! Of course I am assuming here that your SQL server is running in optimum conditions and is not the cause of the slow response!